# How do I fix this grads script?

Tags: grads

This is my gs file.

```
'xloc = aminlocx(slp,lon=120,lon=135,lat=20,lat=30)'
'yloc = aminlocy(slp,lon=120,lon=135,lat=20,lat=30)'

'lonn = 39.58386 + 0.22522523*(xloc-1)'
'latt = -8.64826 + 0.22522523*(yloc-1)'

'lonmin = lonn-1'
'lonmax = lonn+1'
'latmin = latt-1'
'latmax = latt+1'

'q w2xy   'lonmin' 'latmin
xpos1=subwrd(result,3)
ypos1=subwrd(result,6)

'q w2xy  'lonmax' 'latmax
xpos2=subwrd(result,3)
ypos2=subwrd(result,6)

'set line 2 1 6'  
'draw rec 'xpos1' 'ypos1' 'xpos2' 'ypos2
```

And I got error like this

```
Query Error: Syntax is QUERY W2XY Lon Lat

Query Error: Syntax is QUERY W2XY Lon Lat

DRAW error: Syntax is DRAW REC xlo ylo xhi yhi
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: When looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660972/how-to-draw-a-square-in-grads/33678929#33678929) I think your are missing a closing `'` at the end of the lines containing `w2xy`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that there are two types of variables in the GrADS script. One is a script variable and the other is a GrADS variable. The former variable must be outside of the quotes and the latter is referenced inside the quotes.
For example, in the following line of your script

```
'q w2xy 'lonmin' 'latmin'
```

`lonmin` and `latmin` are treated as script variables.
On the other hand, in the following line

```
'xloc = aminlocx(cmsk,lon=120,lon=135,lat=20,lat=30)'
```

`xloc` is treated as a GrADS variable.

Now, if you want to get `xloc` as a script variable, you can write as the following.

```
'd aminlocx(cmsk,lon=120,lon=135,lat=20,lat=30)' 
xloc = subwrd(result,4)
```

Alternatively, for contexts where `display` is not allowed, you can also write as the following.

```
'xloc = aminlocx(cmsk,lon=120,lon=135,lat=20,lat=30)' 
'q defval xloc 1 1'
xloc = subwrd(result,3)
```

Finally, your script will be rewritten like this.

```
'd aminlocx(cmsk,lon=120,lon=135,lat=20,lat=30)' 
xloc = subwrd(result,4)
'd aminlocy(cmsk,lon=120,lon=135,lat=20,lat=30)'
yloc = subwrd(result,4)

lonn = 120.0 + 0.22522523*(xloc-1)
latt = 20.0 + 0.22522523*(yloc-1)

lonmin = lonn-1
lonmax = lonn+1
latmin = latt-1
latmax = latt+1

'q w2xy   'lonmin' 'latmin
xpos1=subwrd(result,3)
ypos1=subwrd(result,6)
'q w2xy   'lonmax' 'latmax
xpos2=subwrd(result,3)
ypos2=subwrd(result,6)

'set line 2 1 6'  
'draw rec 'xpos1' 'ypos1' 'xpos2' 'ypos2
```